C# Datatable contains duplicate row- Need to find the duplicate
I have data table in c# and it contains more columns and rows I need to find the duplicate row and show the row number. Data table always comes with undefined column names it’s not fixed columns.Anyone please help me on this ?
What I have tried:
I tried with Linq but getting the error.
Error:"The source contains no DataRows".
Dt =dr.AsEnumerable().Except(DT1.AsEnumerable(),System.Data.DataRow compared.Default).CopyTiDataTable();

What I have tried:
I tried with Linq but getting the error.
Dt =dr.AsEnumerable().Except(DT1.AsEnumerable(),System.Data.DataRow compared.Default).CopyTiDataTable();

Error:The source contains no DataRows.

.Except() won't work here - it doesn't have the same semantics as in SQL.

What is your definition of duplicate? A DataRow has no a compare/equals method build in i know of. So you have todo comparing of values in the rows yourself. Here is one example https://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable-compare-rows


I have data table in c# and it contains more columns and rows I need to find the duplicate row and show the row number

This is not a precise requirement. Are there duplicate rows? And if there is one, which row number do you want to show, the first row, or the 2nd one? And what if a row is repeated three times? Is that also considered a "duplicate row", and which number would you want to show? All three? Only the first, or only the 2nd and third? And can it be that there are several duplicate rows? Do you want to show them all, or is showing one of them enough?
Let's assume you want the following.

Requirement Given an object of class System.Data.DataTable, which has zero or more rows. Some of these rows might have duplicates, meaning that a given equality comparer would define them equal. Give me the sequence of unique rows, each with the row numbers that contain the values of these rows.

For example, the following sequence (preceded by their index)
[0]  A
[1]  B
[2]  C
[3]  B
[4]  D
[5]  D
[6]  C
[7]  E
[8]  C

Row [0] and [7] are unique. Rows 1 and [3] are equal, as well as rows [4] and [5]. Rows 2, [6], [8] are also equal.
The result will be:
A - 0
B - 1 3
C - 2 6 8
D - 4 5
E - 7

If you really are not interested in unique rows, simply remove the rows that have only one index attached to it.
First of all, we need something that can decide whether two rows are equal. We have a (user provided?) object of a class that implements
IEqualityComparer<System.Data.DataRow> rowEqualityComparer = ...

It is up to you to decide when two rows are equal: reference equality: they are the same object? Or value equality: they have equal values in their item[]
Okay, so far everything is defined.
System.Data.DataTable table = ...

The table has an enumerable collection of DataRows in property DataTable.Rows.
We need to convert this into an enumerable sequence of DataRows, each with their index:
var rowsWithIndex = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    .Select( (index, row) => new
    {
        Index = index,
        Row = row,
    })

Now we can convert this to a Lookup table using the overload of Enumerable.ToLookup that has a keySelector (= the row), a keyComparer to decide when two rows are equal (= rowEqualityComparer) and an element selector. The elements that belong to a certain key are all indexes that have the same row value as the key.
var result = rowsWithIndex.ToLookup(
    // parameter keySelector: the Row
    // so from every "row with index", take the Row
    rowWithIndex => rowWithIndex.Row,

    // parameter elementSelector: the index
    // so from every "row with index", take the Index
    rowWithIndex => rowWithIndex.Index,

    // use this equality comparer:
    rowEqualityComparer);

So now you have some kind of dictionary, that contains all your distinct rows as keys, and with every key is a sequence of indexes from your table that contains rows equal to the key.
In our example, you would have:
result[B] => 1, 3 (enumerable of int)
result[C] => 2, 6, 8

etc.
Only problem left is your generic equality comparer. If you need to compare by value, I guess the easiest would be to make a factory class that takes your table, reads the number of columns in the table, creates an equality comparer for each cell and declares two rows equal if all cells in the rows are equal.
But you still have to know a little bit what is in the columns. For instance, if there is a string value in the column, giving the city, is "Amsterdam" the same city as "amsterdam"? And is the time "3 am" the same as "15:00"?
